# confusion regarding the time of complexity of constat array size

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I researched why the following code is still O(N), even if we put the "const" keyword before the input array size.

```
const int array_size = 10 
for (int i= 0 ; i < array_size; i++)
{
  ...
}
```

Why the **complexity time** is still O(N)?

Comment: Zero iterations through the loop would be O(1).  One iteration O(n).  Nested iterations O(n²).  Iterations based on n would be O(n!).

Comment: according to [Big O Notation calculator](https://shunnarski.github.io/BigO.html) `for (int i= 0 ; i < 6; i++)` is o(1), even the loop has not input value.

Comment: David's explanation is correct.  I was presuming array_size was variable in some fashion, even if that fashion was to change it and recompile.

Answer (score 3):

What time complexity refers to is the order of growth of a function as the input size increases. It has nothing to do with language-specific features like the `const` keyword.

In your example the time complexity is constant, or O(1), because the number of iterations is not dependent on the size of some input. The `const` keyword is a keyword in the C++ language that means that the variable itself can't be changed, but time complexity is a general computer science concept. Whether or not `array_size` is `const`, the number of iterations is the same.